# PHP preg_match function always return false?

Tags: php

I have just started learning PHP days ago and was getting hands on with the `preg_match()` function, I wonder why the following always returns false?

```
preg_match('[A-Z]{2}', 'CA')
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php  <--read this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That isn't a valid regular expression, you're missing the delimiters, change to:

```
preg_match('/[A-Z]{2}/', 'CA')
```

`/` is a common delimiter but you can use any delimiter you want (so long as it's not alphanumeric, a backslash nor whitespace):

```
preg_match('@[A-Z]{2}@', 'CA')
preg_match('%[A-Z]{2}%', 'CA')
```

---

You will also get a warning or notice about missing delimiters. Turn on/up your error reporting level.